Unable to play video content in NextJS with CloudFront signed cookies
Summary
Currently I'm trying to build a website that displays private videos based on user privileges. I'm hosting the frontend with NextJS (http://localhost:3000) and the backend with NestJS (http://localhost:5000). I'm storing the video in a private S3 bucket, and use CloudFront to generate signed cookies (if user is authorized) and display the content.
The Problem
If I access the video directly https://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/video/intro.mp4, and the cookies: CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id, CloudFront-Policy, CloudFront-Signature are stored correctly in the browser page I can view the video just fine. However if I try to play this in my video player in the NextJS app in (http://localhost:3000) the video does not play and it returns 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource..
The Setup
S3 Bucket
CORS Policy
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ]
    }
]

Bucket Policy
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxx-private/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::xxxxxx"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

CloudFront
Origin Request Policy

NestJS
Main
app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
  });

Controller
async access() {
          const cookies = await this.service.getAccess(id);

          response.cookie(
            'CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id',
            cookies['CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id'],
            {
              domain: 'localhost',
              httpOnly: true,
            },
          );
          response.cookie('CloudFront-Policy', cookies['CloudFront-Policy'], {
            domain: 'localhost',
            httpOnly: true,
          });
          response.cookie(
            'CloudFront-Signature',
            cookies['CloudFront-Signature'],
            {
              domain: 'localhost',
              httpOnly: true,
            },
          );

    return 'Success';
  }

NextJS
API call
const response = await axios.get(`${this.client}/${url}`, {
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${getCookie("Access-Token")}`,
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      });

Error
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The CORS policy you shared clearly allows only cloudfront. Can you try adding "localhost" to it or say "*" and test to verify if that is the problem?

I've updated the S3 CORS Policy to "AllowedOrigins": [ "*"  ], but the error is still there. Thanks for replying by the way.

Sorry, its not an issues with AWS. This seems to be between your frontend and backend. Can you simply say "app.enableCors()" and see?

I tried with just app.enableCors() and the error persists. I need to keep the credentials on as I use it to authenticate the user with email and password

The "credentials" here doesn't mean the username and password. If it is true then all cookies associated to that origin will be automatically sent to the server in each request. I recommend trying without anything "app.enableCors()" or atleast remove the origin property from it.

Or try saying "*" in origin in app.enableCors

I tried with just "app.enableCors()", I still receive the error, I was leaning on thinking it was related to the AWS CloudFront configuration with CORS

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This doesn't seem like an issue with Cloudfront or your bucket policy. Since it works well when you load directly from the browser. I think this might be due to your next.config.js configuration. What do you currently have in your remotePatterns array ? If you haven't added the cloudfront hostname, the CORS error will persist. Kindly do this and you should be able to access your video resource


module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'xxxxxx.cloudfront.net', // Your CloudFront domain
        pathname: '/video/*', // The path pattern for the video
      },
    ],
  },
};



